# What safety measures should I take when operating a backyard aluminum furnace

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety, metallurgy

I have made a DIY furnaces out of cement. Before I do any smelting, I would just like to take any suggestions in regards to any safety measures I should take.

I plan to only melt aluminum cans and small parts. I then plan to pour them onto a flat plane to make aluminum plates. Later I plan to make casts.

My furnace is very similar to the one pictured below.
[image]

I plan to connect a hair drier to the hole (with an extension metal rod) in order to increase air flow. It will operate by burning charcoal brickets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this up in an area free of leaves and debris.

I recommend wearing safety gear: heat resistant goggles and fire-resistance clothing and gloves that will protect you from heat, especially when pouring.

Get a couple practice runs in pouring before using it so you get a feel for the best angle to hold in and learn what NOT to do. Even better, you could assemble something that would do the pouring for you. (I'm thinking of [something along the lines of this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/US_Navy_111021-N-ZZ999-001_Shipbuilders_Jason_West,_left,_and_Kevin_Forrest_pour_molten_pewter_into_a_mold_for_production_of_the_Quicken_Loans_Carr.jpg), but it doesn't have to be as elaborate.)

You may also want to scrape the paint off the cans before putting them in. Otherwise, you'll  get a lot of crud from the paint in your molten aluminum.